# Set hard-wrap at 68 columns for one session

Tags: emacs, elisp

I would like to be able to start emacs from the command line in such a way that for the entirety of that emacs session, my lines hard wrap at 68 columns.

This will be called in a script.

I was previously using vim for this, calling `vim -c "set tw=68"`

Is there an equivalent for emacs?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that by "hard-wrap" you mean that when you type past column 68 the text is moved to a new line.

To do that, use `C-u 68 C-x f`. That sets the `fill-column` at column 68.

You can do the following either in the command line using `--eval` as @Stefan suggested or in the command line by loading a file that has this code:

```
(progn
  (add-hook 'auto-fill-mode-hook (lambda () (set-fill-column 20)))
  (auto-fill-mode 1))
```

That makes `auto-fill-mode` set the `fill-column` to 20, and then it turns on `auto-fill-mode`.

Comment: Set it (i.e., customize it) as a user option. Then it will always be in effect when you start Emacs - no need for a command-line option. (And I'm not aware of a command-line option for this.) You can of course always use command-line-option `-l` to load a Lisp file that contains code that sets such variables. Or you can use command-line option `-f` to execute a function that does that.

Comment: The reason i wanted a command line option was because I have a script that requires an editor to be opened. I want that editor, emacs, to have hard line wrap enabled. I don't want the line wrap to always be enabled for emacs. I will look into the -l and -f options.

Comment: Just put (setq-default fill-column 68) in a file `foo.el`, and use command-line option `-l foo.el`. See [`(emacs) Action Arguments`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Action-Arguments.html#Action-Arguments) for info about the file being a full name or being in your `load-path`.

Comment: Even with this being evaluated on startup I can still type past 68 characters without a line break forming.

Comment: Yes, well you have to turn on `auto-fill-mode` (also), if you want automatic filling.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by "hard line wrap", but Drew's suggestion can be done with

```
emacs --eval '(setq-default fill-column 68)'
```

Comment: By hard line wrap I mean when I type past 68 characters, entering a space results in a new line. This suggestion didnt work, I can still type as many characters as I want with no line breaks.

Comment: Then you additionally need to enable `auto-fill-mode`.  E.g. `emacs --eval '(setq-default fill-column 68)' --eval '(auto-fill-mode 1)'`.  But note that `auto-fill-mode` is buffer-local, not global, so you'll ned to enable it in the particular buffer/mode that you use.